# How do I add an working if to my code? - Java

Tags: java, if-statement

I'm building this weird BMI/BMR calculator for school and right now the code does what I want it to do. But I need to add an if (I think) that makes sure that the user doesn't type in values that are too small or too big. The user is only allowed to type in "vikt" between 0.5 and 2.2. If the user types in a faulty value I need the program to execute an else that prints out a "nope you did it wrong".

My problem is that I do not know where to put the if so that the code still works.
So my question is, where and how do I add an if to my code?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
    
    // Ledtext
    System.out.println("Beräkna ditt BMI");
    System.out.print("Tryck j för att starta: " );    
    char fortsätt = input.next().charAt(0);
    System.out.println(" ");

    do 
    {  
    
    //Användaren matar in sin data    
    System.out.print("Ange personens vikt (kg): ");
    double vikt = input.nextDouble();
    System.out.print("Ange personens längd (m): ");
    double längd = input.nextDouble();
    System.out.print("Ange personens ålder: ");
    double ålder = input.nextDouble();
    
    
    System.out.println(" ");
    System.out.println("Beräknat BMI för både män och kvinnor är " + bmi(vikt, längd));
    System.out.println("Beräknat BMR för män är: " + kalorier_Män(vikt, längd, ålder));
    System.out.println("Beräknat BMR för kvinnor är: "+ kalorier_Kvinnor(vikt, längd, ålder));
    System.out.println(" ");
    System.out.print("Fortsätta? (j/n): ");
    fortsätt = input.next().charAt(0);
    }

while (fortsätt != 'n');
    
}

static double bmi(double vikt, double längd){
    double bmiMänochKvinnor;
    
    bmiMänochKvinnor = (1.3 * vikt) / Math.pow(längd, 2.5);
    return   bmiMänochKvinnor;

} 

static double kalorier_Män (double vikt,double längd,double ålder){
    double manBmr; 
        
    manBmr = (9.99 * vikt) + (6.25 * längd) - (4.92 * ålder) + 5;
    return manBmr;

}

static double kalorier_Kvinnor (double vikt,double längd,double ålder){
    double kvinnaBmr; 
    
    kvinnaBmr = (9.99 * vikt) + (6.25 * längd) - (4.92 * ålder) - 161;
    return kvinnaBmr;
    }


}
```

Comment: Where have you tried to add other conditions other than the do-while? What isn't "working" when you do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can check the values directly after they are read, with an `if else` statement like this:

```
if(vikt > 2.2 || vikt < 0.5){
            System.out.println("nope you did it wrong");
            return; // this will stop the code
        }
```

A better way of handling this problem would be the following function:

```
private static double retrieveValue(Scanner input, double min, double max, String requestMessage){
        while(true){
            System.out.println(requestMessage);

            double measure = input.nextDouble();
            
            if (measure >= min && measure <= max){
                return measure;
            } else{
                System.out.println("This values is not allowed, please try again:");
            }
        }
    }
```

You can call it like this:

```
double vikt = retrieveValue(input, 0.5, 2.2, "Ange personens vikt (kg):");
```

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding you want to constrain the values the user can use as an input for this line:

```
double vikt = input.nextDouble();
```

You can simply do this by adding an if statement right after that where you check the entered value. If the value doesn't match the condition, you can send a message and continue the loop.

```
if (vikt < 0.5 || vikt > 2.2) {
   // send some message
   continue;
}
```